# how to upload multiple files

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload, upload

i like to post a number of images on my site.

it works for single post when i just use one image. as i tried to use with multiple images it doesnt work anymore and i dont understand why this doesnt work. to show my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['var1'];
 ...
 ...        $Bild1 = $_FILES['image1']; 
            $Bild2 = $_FILES['image2'];
            $Bild3 = $_FILES['image3'];
            $Bild4 = $_FILES['image4']; 
            $Bild5 = $_FILES['image5'];
            $Bild6 = $_FILES['image6'];
            $Bild7 = $_FILES['image7'];
            $Bild8 = $_FILES['image8'];
            $Bild9 = $_FILES['image9'];
            $Bild10 = $_FILES['image10'];

                $errors = array();
                $allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');

                $file_name_1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
                $file_name_2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
                $file_name_3 = $_FILES['image3']['name'];
                $file_name_4 = $_FILES['image4']['name'];
                $file_name_5 = $_FILES['image5']['name'];
                $file_name_6 = $_FILES['image6']['name'];
                $file_name_7 = $_FILES['image7']['name'];
                $file_name_8 = $_FILES['image8']['name'];
                $file_name_9 = $_FILES['image9']['name'];
                $file_name_10 = $_FILES['image10']['name'];

                $split_1 = explode('.', $file_name_1);  
                $split_2 = explode('.', $file_name_2);
                $split_3 = explode('.', $file_name_3);
                $split_4 = explode('.', $file_name_4);
                $split_5 = explode('.', $file_name_5);
                $split_6 = explode('.', $file_name_6);
                $split_7 = explode('.', $file_name_7);
                $split_8 = explode('.', $file_name_8);
                $split_9 = explode('.', $file_name_9);
                $split_10 = explode('.', $file_name_10);

                $split_1[0] = '1';
                $split_2[0] = '2';
                $split_3[0] = '3';
                $split_4[0] = '4';
                $split_5[0] = '5';
                $split_6[0] = '6';
                $split_7[0] = '7';
                $split_8[0] = '8';
                $split_9[0] = '9';
                $split_10[0] = '10';

                $file_basename_1 = $split_1[0];
                $file_basename_2 = $split_2[0];
                $file_basename_3 = $split_3[0];
                $file_basename_4 = $split_4[0];
                $file_basename_5 = $split_5[0];
                $file_basename_6 = $split_6[0];
                $file_basename_7 = $split_7[0];
                $file_basename_8 = $split_8[0];
                $file_basename_9 = $split_9[0];
                $file_basename_10 = $split_10[0];

                $file_extension_1 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_1)));
                $file_extension_2 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_2)));
                $file_extension_3 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_3)));
                $file_extension_4 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_4)));
                $file_extension_5 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_5)));
                $file_extension_6 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_6)));
                $file_extension_7 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_7)));
                $file_extension_8 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_8)));
                $file_extension_9 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_9)));
                $file_extension_10 = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name_10)));

                $file_size_1 = $_FILES['image1']['size'];
                $file_size_2 = $_FILES['image2']['size'];
                $file_size_3 = $_FILES['image3']['size'];
                $file_size_4 = $_FILES['image4']['size'];
                $file_size_5 = $_FILES['image5']['size'];
                $file_size_6 = $_FILES['image6']['size'];
                $file_size_7 = $_FILES['image7']['size'];
                $file_size_8 = $_FILES['image8']['size'];
                $file_size_9 = $_FILES['image9']['size'];
                $file_size_10 = $_FILES['image10']['size'];

                $file_tmp_1 = $_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_2 = $_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_3 = $_FILES['image3']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_4 = $_FILES['image4']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_5 = $_FILES['image5']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_6 = $_FILES['image6']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_7 = $_FILES['image7']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_8 = $_FILES['image8']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_9 = $_FILES['image9']['tmp_name'];
                $file_tmp_10 = $_FILES['image10']['tmp_name'];

                $file_newname_1 = $file_basename_1 .".". $file_extension_1;
                $file_newname_2 = $file_basename_2 .".". $file_extension_2;
                $file_newname_3 = $file_basename_3 .".". $file_extension_3;
                $file_newname_4 = $file_basename_4 .".". $file_extension_4;
                $file_newname_5 = $file_basename_5 .".". $file_extension_5;
                $file_newname_6 = $file_basename_6 .".". $file_extension_6;
                $file_newname_7 = $file_basename_7 .".". $file_extension_7;
                $file_newname_8 = $file_basename_8 .".". $file_extension_8;
                $file_newname_9 = $file_basename_9 .".". $file_extension_9;
                $file_newname_10 = $file_basename_10 .".". $file_extension_10;

                $path ='a/b/c/'.$id.'/'.$new_file_id.'/';

                if (in_array($file_extension_1, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage1';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_2, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage2';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_3, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage3';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_4, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage4';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_5, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage5';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_6, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage6';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_7, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage7';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_8, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage8';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_9, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage9';
                }
                if (in_array($file_extension_10, $allowed_extension)=== false){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage10';
                }

                if ($file_size_1 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage1';
                }
                if ($file_size_2 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage2';
                }
                if ($file_size_3 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage3';
                }
                if ($file_size_4 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage4';
                }
                if ($file_size_5 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage5';
                }
                if ($file_size_6 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage6';
                }
                if ($file_size_7 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage7';
                }
                if ($file_size_8 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage8';
                }
                if ($file_size_9 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage9';
                }
                if ($file_size_10 > 2097152){
                    $errors[] = 'errormessage10';
                }

                if (empty($errors)) {

                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_1, $path . $file_newname_1)) {
                    echo 'success1'; 
                }

                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_2, $path . $file_newname_2)) {
                    echo 'success2'; 
                }

                if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_3, $path . $file_newname_3)) {
                    echo 'success3'; 
                }

            }
```

is there also a way to shorten this code? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it so wrong. To much redundancy in your code

```
$allowed_extension = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'tiff', 'gif');
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
   // Carry on like this
   $file_name = $file['name'];
   $size = $file['size'];

   //However, you might want to extract the extension like this
   $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   //...


}
```

Comment: Plus trusting the file's extension to be honest about what's in there, plus asusming the filename has a `.` it, plus assuming the user doesn't embed a hostile path in the `['name']`parameter, plus not checking for upload failure, plus... plus.... plus... OP, please scrap this code and start over, AFTER you've learned about secure file upload handling.

Comment: Yeah, you should check for the file's mime types to ensure a file to be of correct type as @Marc said.